# Compact Framework - Upload file via REST

Tags: rest, compact-framework

I am looking for the best way to transfer files from the compact framework to a server via REST.  I have a web service I created using .net Web API.  I've looked at several SO questions and other sites that dealt with sending files, but none of them seem to work the for what I need.

I am trying to send media files from WM 6 and 6.5 devices to my REST service.  While most of the files are less than 300k, an odd few may be 2-10 or so megabytes.  Does anyone have some snippets I could use to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify what didn't seem to work with the suggestions on the other questions/sites? Otherwise, chances are that the answers here won't work for you either.

Comment: Sure - I saw a few where they were sending xml or text files, which they serialized into a string.  Or some (like protobuf) where they serialize a data structure into a file.  I've also seen some where they use a multi-part protocol, but the compact framework does not support that.

Comment: I see, most examples do involve `multipart/form-data`. You can code that yourself, but indeed there is no need to when just sending a file. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the minimum for sending a file:

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.destination.com/path");
    request.Method = "POST"; // or PUT, depending on what the server expects
    request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length; // see the note below
    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        int bytes;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // any reasonable buffer size will do
        while ((bytes = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {

        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // failure
    }
}
```

Note: HTTP needs a way to know when you're "done" sending data. There are three ways to achieve this:

- Set `request.ContentLength` as used in the example, because we know the size of the file before sending anything
- Set `request.SendChunked`, to send chunks of data including their individual size
- You *could* also set `request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering` to write to an in-memory buffer, but I wouldn't recommend wasting that much memory on the compact framework.

Comment: I tried this and ran into some issues.  First, the CF request stream only allows char arrays.  I was able to use requestStream.BaseStream.Write just fine.  However I'm not sure if this caused an error, as I keep getting an internal server error from my REST app ("The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.").  I'm able to use postman to send test data and it works great, but my CF app makes the server return that error.  This makes me think something is wrong on the CF side.

Comment: There is no limitation that only allows char arrays on the CF (at least not on 2.0 and 3.5). I think the problem is that your service expects the data to be sent in a certain _format_ such as JSON or XML, and if that is the case, the binary data will need to be encoded (ie. using Base64).

Comment: Excellent, it's all working now.  I used a StreamWriter object for the RequestStream, which does not accept byte arrays in read statements (also, you cannot use objects in CF as it doesn't support late binding).  I switched to a Stream object, no problem.  As for the server error, it was working on my local machine while testing with postman.  It didn't work live because of a deployment issue.  Thanks!